# Implementing User Accounts using Shared Preference in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement user accounts by `shared preferences` in android studio. I'm planning to do it by using String arrays, and here is what I've got.

For registering username and password,

```
   public void registerUser(View view){
    SharedPreferences users = getSharedPreferences("usernames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences pass = getSharedPreferences("passwords", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = users.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editpass = pass.edit();
    edit.putInt("array_size", Username.length);
    for(int i=0;i<Username.length; i++)
        edit.putString("array_" + i, Username[i]);
    editpass.putInt("array_size", Passwords.length);
    for(int i=0;i<Passwords.length; i++)
        edit.putString("array_" + i, Passwords[i]);
    edit.commit();
    editpass.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved both user and pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And I'm trying to verify it by using this code on my login page,

```
 public void login(View view) {
    SharedPreferences users = getSharedPreferences("usernames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences pass = getSharedPreferences("passwords", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    CurrentUser = tvuser.getText().toString();
    CurrentPassword = tvpass.getText().toString();
    int size = users.getInt("array_size", 0);
    String[] array = new String[size];
    String cuser;
    String cpass;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cuser = users.getString("array_" + i, null);
        if (cuser.equals(CurrentUser)) {
            cpass = pass.getString("array_" + i, null);
            if (cpass.equals(CurrentPassword)) {
                Intent in = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Username or Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The registering is functioning but the login does not work.
Any help would be appreciated. I need to do this by shared preferences. I know that there are easier way like using databases. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No need to define multiple `SharedPreference`. Use one and store values in that one.

Comment: @ShaishavJogani so all of my strings will be inside one SharedPreference? how would i differentiate username and passwords then?

Comment: It's better to use SQLite though.

Comment: So do you need to store more than one user/password in shared preferences?

Comment: Yes and i would like to compare it to the login for the login authentication and also on registration so that there would be no duplicate accounts.

Comment: @Miho Just give different key names for userName and Password. Here, in your code you are giving same name i.e. array for both user names and passwords, which I think is not good way. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm